# AWS Get SQS queue name from ReceiptHandle

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sqs

Is it possibile get a name of SQS queue from a receiptHandle? I didn't find any information about how it's generated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> *I didn't find any information about how it's generated.*

There is no information about how SQS receipt handles are generated, because from the user perspective, a receipt handle is just that -- a [handle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)) -- an abstract value which (as far as the user is concerned) is (or might as well be) completely opaque.

A receipt handle is generated by SQS itself (not the SDK).  It identifies (to an SQS queue) one specific receive event of one specific message from that queue. Exactly how they are generated and how they might be interpreted (assuming they aren't just very large random numbers) is never mentioned.

The [`DeleteMessage` API Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html) requires that you pass both the `QueueUrl` and the `ReceiptHandle`.  This implies -- though of course it does not actually prove -- that the receipt handle doesn't identify the queue... but if it did identify the queue, there seems to be no reason SQS would need you to identify the queue with which the receipt handle is associated.